# Change URL depending on parameters in URL

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have the following jQuery code:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "?start_price=" + start_price + "&end_price=" + end_price + "&order_by=" + order_by);
```

This works fine for taking everything behind the parameter "?" and change it and send the user back to the original URL with the customization behind "?"

Ex: http://example.com/80?start_price=80&end_price=120&order_by=price

The URL can have the following pattern:

```
1. http://example.com?start_price=80&end_price=120&order_by=price
2. http://example.com/80?start_price=80&end_price=120&order_by=price
3. http://example.com/120?start_price=80&end_price=120&order_by=price
```

Now I want to send the user (independent what the parameters after ? is) to URL style 1, without the 80 or 120 in it.

I use this code for displaying products. And the numbers are pagination numbers. So basically I want the user to come to the first page when the user change any of the parameters of start_price, end_price or order_by.

Im not good at this some one who can give a hint here?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so a user can't go directly to the page they want using the URL (restricting them to browsing to it essentially)?

Comment: The user are able to go directly, and Im not trying to disable that possibility. Its just when the user is on e.g. page 3 of the product page (watching products) and then decides to filter the products, the user should automatically come to page 1. As it is now the user will stay at page 3 with the filtering (which the user choosed) enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this ?

```
var parts = window.location.pathname.split('/'); //pathname to array
parts.splice(parts.length-1,1); // kill the last key
var newpathname = parts.join('/'); // reassemble

self.location.href = window.location.protocol+'://'+window.location.host+'/'+newpathname+'?'+window.location.search;
```

(not tested, but should work)